# Firebase Push Notifications Pricing

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I was wondering why I was billed for using FCM throughout my app development lifecycle although FCM is priced for free here:
[https://firebase.google.com/pricing][1]

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried contacting google?

Answer (score 1):

FCM is free to use. But billing may have been incurred due to how those notifications have been invoked, for example, were you using cloud functions to monitor your FiresTore or RealTime Database? These invocations aren't for free. Can you share the bill break-up?

Comment: Ok thank you. Actually I am just using FCM for firing the notifications.